# Shortcode content output but not in correct place

Tags: php, functions, shortcode, css, html

I have created a shortcode that gets information from an ACF repeater field...

```
function display_websites_shortcode() {

    ob_start();

    // check if the repeater field has rows of data
    if( have_rows('streaming') ):
        while ( have_rows('streaming') ) : the_row();

            // Your loop code          
            echo '<a href="' . the_sub_field('website_url') . '" >' . the_sub_field('website_source') . '</a>';     

        endwhile;
    else :
        // no rows found        
        echo '<p>No Websites Available</p>';            
    endif;

    return ob_get_clean();
}   
add_shortcode( 'display_websites', 'display_websites_shortcode' );
```

The output/loop works but the content is outside the HTML. So, instead of this...

```
<a href="http://google.com">Google</a>
```

We get this...

`http://google.comGoogle`

I have other shortcodes working using similar code, I just can't figure this out. I've checked other posts with similar issues but nothing stands out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in 99% of cases, `the_*()` functions will echo out the content. If you're assigning them you would need to use `get_*()` functions.

In your case you're echoing twice, once at the beginning of the link and again with `the_*()` function in the attribute and between the opening and closing tags. It breaks the string concatenation you have in place by echoing more than once.

Your code should look like:

```
echo '<a href="' . get_sub_field('website_url') . '" >' . get_sub_field('website_source') . '</a>';
```

Comment: This is a shortcode, it shouldn't be using `echo` at all

Comment: @TomJNowell You're right but in the posted example they are output buffering.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the reason i use  ob_start() rather than returning the content is that the code is cleaner.

Comment: @TomJNowell Can you please tell me why you shouldn't use ob_start() in a shortcode?

Comment: I don't think anything is inherently bad with using output buffering other than it can be more difficult to debug PHP errors that occur in the buffered output.

Comment: @StuartMoir I actually didn't spot the output buffers, they're fine as long as you close them properly afterwards